# Command only saving one part of a Network's SSID?

Tags: windows, cmd, ssid

While creating a program that would output a networks `SSID` when run I ran into a problem where only a portion of the `SSID` was being outputted. The command I used to find and output the `SSID` was:

```
cd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" & for /f "tokens=2* delims=: " %A in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr "SSID" ^| findstr /v "BSSID"') do set A=%A
```

If, for example my network's `SSID` was "`Bob's Wifi`", the command would output "`Bob's`" rather than "`Bob's Wifi`".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the options of the `for /f`. The clause `tokens=2*` is not asking to retrieve the second and following tokens into the `for` replaceable parameter `%A`, it retrieves the second token into `%A` and the third and following tokens into `%B`. It is equivalent to

```
for /f "tokens=2,* ..."
```

I can not test the code (no wlan), but this shuld solve the problem

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %A  ..... do set "networkName=%B"
```

now the field name (the token in the left side of the colon) is stored in `%A` and the full name (second to end tokens in the line) are stored into `%B`